# Borrar datos tabla PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin, apache

Estoy intentando crear un botón, usando PHP, que al hacer click borre los datos almacenados del usuario que tiene la sesión iniciada.
He probado de varias maneras pero no lo he conseguido.
Soy novato en PHP, le he hecho muchos cambios al código para ir probando y así es como lo tengo actualmente. Espero que me podáis ayudar.

```
<div id="borrar">
   <button id="btn5" onclick="location.href='borrado.php';">Borrar mis datos</button>
 </div>
```

**Archivo borrado.php:**

```
require_once("libreria.php");
session_start();

  function borrar($id_cliente) {
      try {

          $conn = conectar();
          $id_cliente = $_SESSION['id_cliente'];
          $sql = "DELETE FROM datos WHERE id_cliente =$id_cliente";
          $st = $conn->prepare($sql);

      } catch (Exception $e) {
          echo $e->getMessage();
      }
  }
  header('Location:perfil.php');
```

Answer (score 1):

Estas definiendo la función pero no la llamas posteriormente, tampoco ejecutas la sentencia del PDO, te quedas en el prepare, podrías hacer en el php pero sin declarar una función, algo como:

```
try {
    $conn = conectar();
    $id_cliente = $_SESSION['id_cliente'];
    $sql = "DELETE FROM datos WHERE id_cliente = ?";
    $st = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $st->execute(array($id_cliente));
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
header('Location:perfil.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

En base al codigo que has puesto yo lo dejaria algo asi:

```
<?php
require_once('libreria.php');
session_start();
function borrar($id_cliente) {

// Validar los datos de entrada siempre. Puede fallar por no envias nada
if (empty($id_cliente)){
  throw new Exception('Id cliente no valido');
}
      // controlar siempre los errores eso esta muy bien pero los tienes que 
      // sacar de la funcion
      try {
          $conn = conectar();
          
          // esto coge el valor de la sesion no de la variable de la funcion
          // $id_cliente = $_SESSION['id_cliente'];

          $sql = "DELETE FROM datos WHERE id_cliente = '$id_cliente'";
          $conn->prepare($sql)->execute();
      } catch (Exception $e) {
        throw new Exception($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode());
      }
  }


try {
  borrar($_SESSION['id_cliente']);
  header('Location:perfil.php');
}catch (Exception $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```